# apex static files apex4.0.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, static-files

I am using Apex4.0.2.

Does anyone know what kind of query Shared Components / Static Files uses?

It is certainly a view on WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$.
But looking at view APEX_WORKSPACE_FILES not all 
(workspace_id - workspace_name - application_id - application_name - mime_type)
appear in Shared Components / Static Files

I am using Ant to assemble and upload static files to oracle because it's quicker than using the interface. The result in WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$ is usable but doesn't appear in the interface under Shared Components / Static Files which would be good to have.

Is there an auxilliary table involved?

Alastair

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is *don't do this*. Messing around with undocumented, internal storage is probably going to end in heartbreak. Do you never intend to upgrade your Apex instance? Who knows if this will keep working once you do that. I'm assuming this is "too slow" as you move an application from one instance to another?

My first suggestion is **upgrade to Apex 5.x**. When you do an application export, the application files (not the workspace files) go with the application and are installed when you install the application. Which, by the way, you can do from `sqlplus` in a script.

If you're stuck with Apex 4.x for the moment, what I did was to add the files to the application, then create an install script (I forget what section of Apex you do that in) that installs the files. This is a little annoying, because every time you change the file, you have to delete the script and recreate it.